# Can I travel to a Schengen Country on Multiple Entry C-type Visa issued by a different country?

Tags: schengen

I have a multiple entry C-type Visa issued by Switzerland, valid until 2020, and period of stay 90 days. I've already been to Switzerland with that visa before, and stayed for around 20 days. Now I need to go for a short visit to Germany for 3 days. Can I use the same visa or I need to apply a new one?

Comment: Please use search. This question is asked here on a weekly basis.

Comment: Schengen type B visas were abolished several years ago.  The only types in current use are A, C, and D.  You may want to check your visa type once again.

Comment: Thanks @Neusser, I overlooked the already answered questions. I got my answer. :)

Comment: @phoog: Yes, you're right, it's a Schengen C-type VISA with Multiple Entry